# Pythonic way to determine whether not null list entries are 'continuous'

Tags: python, list, null, slice

**I'm looking for a way to easily determine if all not None items in a list occur in a single continuous slice.**  I'll use integers as examples of not None items.

For example, the list `[None, None, 1, 2, 3, None, None]` meets my requirements for continuous  integer entries.  By contrast, `[1, 2, None, None, 3, None]` is **not** continuous, because there are None entries between integers.

Some more examples to make this a clear as possible.

**Continuous**:
   `[1, 2, 3, None, None]`
   `[None, None, 1, 2, 3]`
   `[None, 1, 2, 3, None]`

**Not Continuous**:
   `[None, 1, None, 2, None, 3]`
   `[None, None, 1, None, 2, 3]`
   `[1, 2, None, 3, None, None]`

My first approach was to use variables to keep track of whether or not we had come across a `None` yet, and whether or not we had come across an `int` yet -- this ends up with a highly nested and very difficult to follow series of if/else statements embedded in a for loop.  (On top of the ugliness, I confess I haven't gotten it to work in every case).

Anyone know an easier way to figure out if the not None items in a list occur in a single continuous slice?

Comment: What result would you expect for a sequence of None (`[None, None, None, None]`)?

Comment: That is an important question for the general problem, but for my specific needs, it wouldn't really matter whether `[None, None, None]` is determined to be continuous or not.  What I'm actually doing is grabbing the first set of not None items, and then doing stuff with them -- what exactly it is that I do depends on whether it is the only continuous slice.  So -- all None's wouldn't even get me to the first step in the process.  But, theoretically, it should probably return True, right?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that the list contains at least one non-None item, please edit that into the question. And what about the cases where the list is length-zero `[]`, or None? Should it give True, False, None, raise exception or you totally don't care? For simplicity, we might as well (retro-)define the don't-care behavior according to what turns out to be most Pythonic.

Comment: Btw, the appropriate word is 'contiguous' not 'continuous'.

Comment: What result do you require for `[3, 1, 2, None, None]`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
def contiguous(seq):
    seq = iter(seq)
    all(x is None for x in seq)        # Burn through any Nones at the beginning
    any(x is None for x in seq)        # and the first group
    return all(x is None for x in seq) # everthing else (if any) should be None.
```

Here are a couple of examples. You can use `next(seq)` to get the next item from an iterator. I'll put a mark pointing to the next item after each

example1:

```
seq = iter([None, 1, 2, 3, None])        #  [None, 1, 2, 3, None]
                                         # next^
all(x is None for x in seq)            
                                         #        next^
any(x is None for x in seq)            
                                         #                    next^ (off the end)
return all(x is None for x in seq)       # all returns True for the empty sequence
```

example2:

```
seq = iter([1, 2, None, 3, None, None])  #    [1, 2, None, 3, None, None]
                                         # next^
all(x is None for x in seq)            
                                         #    next^
any(x is None for x in seq)            
                                         #             next^  
return all(x is None for x in seq)       # all returns False when 3 is encountered
```

Comment: So simple ... Yet so right.  darn... wish I had thought of it.

Comment: Note that your comments aren't exactly right (I think).  You'll burn through all the None's at the beginning plus the first non-None with the first `all`.  I don't think that changes the result though.

Comment: +1, because this is very clever, and I never would have thought of it.  I'm not totally sold on the use of `any` and `all` for side-effect purposes of advancing an iterator, but I haven't got a good argument against it.

Comment: After trying to look up how this worked, I'm a bit stumped -- according to the docs, all() and any() return True or False depending on the contents of their input... and yet they seem to be used to modify their input in place here.  You know where I might find some docs explaining how this works?

Comment: @mgilson, there wasn't enough room in the margin :) You are correct though

Comment: @ClayWardell, the trick is to make seq an iterator. Then `any` and `all` move the iterator along (consume it) even though I don't need the return value of the first two.

Comment: -1 because your are using implicit implementation details of `all` & `any`. While this is a clever use of iterators, I would never recommend this kind of programming tricks. You have to respect the semantics of the stl. In the current case, `groupby` make the solution easier to understand.

Comment: @Simon, It uses _defined_ behaviour of all and any. Why do you think it's implicit? What do you mean by stl?

Comment: @gnibbler - could you please explain in the answer why this works, as per Clay's comment it is not really pbvious

Comment: @gnibbler just look at the [definitions of `all`/ `any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) in the docs. The lazyness of those functions is never explicitly stated. You can deduce it from the `equivalent to` snippets. I would still put this particular behavior in the undocumented part of the function, and would not rely on that (except for performances). Just look at the comments asking for clarifications. Your version is harder to understand.

Comment: @Simon, so you're saying that the short-circuit behaviour of any/all is not explicit? That would have terrible performance implications for a lot of code. Some people think this version is easier to read, so I guess it's subjective

Comment: @gnibbler [dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) or takewhile are explicit about this behavior. any/all are not. I would rather go with those functions if I wanted to implement your version.

Comment: @Simon It *is* explicitly stated. The documentation *states* that `any` and `all` are **equivalent** to those pieces of code. Equivalent means that using the built-in function or the sample code should always produce the same results. Since the sample codes are lazy then also built-in `any` and `all` must be lazy. The doc's writers simply decided that instead of pointing out one by one all the corner cases and things about these simple function their properties well better explained with a small piece of readable code.

Comment: `You'll burn through all the None's at the beginning plus the first non-None with the first all.` Would this fail on [None,1,None,2,3,None] or [None,None,1,None] then?

Comment: @Rob, it's easy enough to just try those cases. The first one returns `False` and the second returns `True` as expected.

Comment: -1 because unreadable at first sight, which IMHO does not qualify as "pythonic way"

Answer (score 25):

Good 'ol `itertools.groupby` to the rescue:

```
from itertools import groupby

def contiguous(seq):
    return sum(1 for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x is not None) if k) == 1
```

gives

```
>>> contiguous([1,2,3,None,None])
True
>>> contiguous([None, 1,2,3,None])
True
>>> contiguous([None, None, 1,2,3])
True
>>> contiguous([None, 1, None, 2,3])
False
>>> contiguous([None, None, 1, None, 2,3])
False
>>> contiguous([None, 1, None, 2, None, 3])
False
>>> contiguous([1, 2, None, 3, None, None])
False
```

[edit]

Since there seems to be some discussion in the comments, I'll explain why I like this approach better than some of the others.

We're trying to find out whether there is one contiguous group of non-None objects, and

```
sum(1 for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x is not None) if k)
```

counts the number of contiguous non-None objects, using the function in the stdlib which is designed for making collecting contiguous groups.  As soon as we see `groupby`, we think "contiguous groups", and vice-versa.  In that sense, it's self-documenting.  This is basically the *definition* of my goal.

IMHO the only weakness is that it doesn't short-circuit, and that could be fixed, but after thinking about it some I still prefer this as it uses a primitive I like -- "count the number of contiguous non-None groups" -- which I prefer to simply "tell me whether or not there is more than one contiguous non-None group as soon as you can".

Many of the approaches to implement the last one rely on clever observations about the problem, like "if there's only one contiguous group of not-None objects, then if we scan until we find the first not-None object, and then scan through objects until we find the first non-None group if one exists, then whether anything's left is None gives us our answer."  (Or something like that, which is part of my issue: I have to think about it.)  To me that feels like using "implementation details" about the problem to solve it, and focuses on properties of the problem we can use to solve it, rather than simply specifying the problem to Python and letting Python do the work.

I'm a bear of very little brain, as the saying has it, and I like to avoid having to be clever, as in my experience it's a route littered with FAIL.

As always, everyone's mileage may vary, of course, and probably in proportion to their cleverness.

Comment: can't you use `any` or `all` instead of `sum`? Seems wasteful to look through the whole list if you don't need to.

Comment: @gnibbler: I can't immediately see how to use `any` or `all`.  I guess you could use `len(list(islice((k for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x is not None) if k), 0, 2))) == 1` or something, but I don't like the look of it much.

Comment: This is better than mine.  +1

Comment: @DSM, i found a way using `all`. Surprisingly it doesn't use groupby

Answer (score 12):

You could use something like `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def are_continuous(items):
    saw_group = False

    for group, values in groupby(items, lambda i: i is not None):
        if group:
            if saw_group:
                return False
            else:
                saw_group = True

    return True
```

This will iterate only until it sees a group twice. I'm not sure if you consider `[None, None]`, so tweak it to your needs.

Comment: I like this one because it's clearer than @DSM's and "shortcircuits" when it can.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be the best way to go about doing it, but you can look for the first non-None entry and the last `non-None` entry and then check the slice for `None`.  e.g.:

```
def is_continuous(seq):
    try:
        first_none_pos = next(i for i,x in enumerate(seq) if x is not None)
        #need the or None on the next line to handle the case where the last index is `None`.
        last_none_pos = -next(i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(seq)) if x is not None) or None
    except StopIteration: #list entirely of `Nones`
        return False
    return None not in seq[first_none_pos:last_none_pos]

assert is_continuous([1,2,3,None,None]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, 1,2,3,None]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, None, 1,2,3]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, 1, None, 2,3]) == False
assert is_continuous([None, None, 1, None, 2,3]) == False
assert is_continuous([None, 1, None, 2, None, 3]) == False
assert is_continuous([1, 2, None, 3, None, None]) == False
```

This will work for any sequence type.

Answer (score 7):

The natural way to consume sequence elements is to use `dropwhile`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def continuous(seq):
    return all(x is None for x in dropwhile(lambda x: x is not None,
                                            dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, seq)))
```

We can express this without nested function calls:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def continuous(seq):
    core = dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, seq)
    remainder = dropwhile(lambda x: x is not None, core)
    return all(x is None for x in remainder)
```

Comment: IIUC, this is the `dropwhile` version of @gnibbler's?

Answer (score 5):

One liner:

```
contiguous = lambda l: ' ' not in ''.join('x '[x is None] for x in l).strip()
```

The real work is done by the `strip` function. If there are spaces in a stripped string, then they're not leading/trailing. The rest of the function converts the list to a string, which has a space for each `None`.

Comment: Although might there be a problem if the data types in the list were not coercible to strings? It might not have been clear in the question, but I was using integers strictly as an easy example -- I need the algorithm to work for all not None data types.

Comment: @ClayWardell If you change `x==None` to `x is None` then it will work for any value type (and will probably be a little faster, as well).

Comment: Thanks @EdwardLoper, I actually didn't know the `is` operator and thought `==` is good enough here.

Comment: `contiguous = lambda l:`? Why name an anonymous function rather than declare a function `def contiguous(l):`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, So you can see it all, without a horizontal scroll bar. Not such a good reason, I admit (I probably spend too much time at [codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: `c=lambda l:' 'not in''.join('x '[x==None]for x in l).strip()`, I think you will love this, golfer.

Answer (score 3):

I did some profiling to compare @gnibbler's approach with the groupby approach.  @gnibber's approach is consistently faster, esp. for longer lists.  E.g., I see about a 50% performance gain for random inputs with length 3-100, with a 50% chance of containing a single int sequence (randomly selected), and otherwise with random values.  Test code below.  I interspersed the two methods (randomly selecting which one goes first) to make sure any caching effects get cancelled out.  Based on this, I'd say that while the groupby approach is more intuitive, @gnibber's approach may be appropriate if profiling indicates that this is an important part of the overall code to optimize -- in that case, appropriate comments should be used to indicate what's going on with the use of all/any to consumer iterator values.

```
from itertools import groupby
import random, time

def contiguous1(seq):
    # gnibber's approach
    seq = iter(seq)
    all(x is None for x in seq)        # Burn through any Nones at the beginning
    any(x is None for x in seq)        # and the first group
    return all(x is None for x in seq) # everthing else (if any) should be None.

def contiguous2(seq):
    return sum(1 for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x is not None) if k) == 1

times = {'contiguous1':0,'contiguous2':0}

for i in range(400000):
    n = random.randint(3,100)
    items = [None] * n
    if random.randint(0,1):
        s = random.randint(0,n-1)
        e = random.randint(0,n-s)
        for i in range(s,e):
            items[i] = 3
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            if not random.randint(0,2):
                items[i] = 3
    if random.randint(0,1):
        funcs = [contiguous1, contiguous2]
    else:
        funcs = [contiguous2, contiguous1]
    for func in funcs:
        t0 = time.time()
        func(items)
        times[func.__name__] += (time.time()-t0)

print
for f,t in times.items():
    print '%10.7f %s' % (t, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution inspired by numpy. Get the array indices of all the non-null elements. Then, compare each index to the one following it. If the difference is greater than one, there are nulls in between the non-nulls. If there are no indices where the following index is more than one greater, then there are no gaps.

```
def is_continuous(seq):
    non_null_indices = [i for i, obj in enumerate(seq) if obj is not None]
    for i, index in enumerate(non_null_indices[:-1]):
        if non_null_indices[i+1] - index > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm does the work with a few drawbacks (it removes items form the list). But it's  a solution.

Basically if you remove all continuous `None` from start and the end. And if you found some `None` in the list then the integers are not in a continuous form.

```
def is_continuous(seq):
    while seq and seq[0] is None: del seq[0]
    while seq and seq[-1] is None: del seq[-1]

    return None not in seq

assert is_continuous([1,2,3,None,None]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, 1,2,3,None]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, None, 1,2,3]) == True
assert is_continuous([None, 1, None, 2,3]) == False
assert is_continuous([None, None, 1, None, 2,3]) == False
assert is_continuous([None, 1, None, 2, None, 3]) == False
assert is_continuous([1, 2, None, 3, None, None]) == False
```

Yet, another example of how small code could become evil.

I wish a `strip()` method were available for `list`.

Answer (score 1):

> My first approach was to use variables to keep track ...
>
> ...this ends up with a highly nested and very difficult to follow series of if/else statements embedded in a for loop...

No! Actually you need only one variable. Thinking this problem in the view of Finite State Machine(FSM) with your approach will lead to a quite nice solution.

We call the state `p`. At first, `p` is 0. Then we start walking between the states.

[image: FSM]

When all the elements in the list is examinated and still don't fail then the answer is `True`.

One version that encode the translation table in a dict

```
def contiguous(s, _D={(0,0):0, (0,1):1, (1,0):2, (1,1):1, (2,0):2, (2,1):3}):
    p = 0
    for x in s:
        p = _D[p, int(x is not None)]
        if p >= 3: return False
    return True
```

Another version that use if statement:

```
def contiguous(s):
    p = 0
    for x in s:
        if x is None and p == 1 or x is not None and (p == 0 or p == 2):
            p += 1
        if p >= 3: return False
    return True
```

So my point is that using `if` and `for` are still pythonic.

### update

I found another way to encode the FSM. We can pack the translation table into a 12bit integer.

```
def contiguous(s):
    p = 0
    for x in s:
        p = (3684 >> (4*p + 2*(x!=None))) & 3
        if p >= 3: return False
    return True
```

Here 3684, the magic number, can be obtained by:

```
    _D[p,a]     3  2  1  2  1  0
         p      2  2  1  1  0  0
         a      1  0  1  0  1  0
bin(3684) = 0b 11 10 01 10 01 00
```

The readability is not as good as other version but it's faster since it avoids dictionary lookup.
The second version is as fast as this but this encoding idea can be generalized to solve more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way just using numpy :

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 6, 7])

# This returns indices of nans
# eg. [[3], [6]]
# use .squeeze() to convert to [3, 6]
aa = np.argwhere(a != a).squeeze()

# use a diff on your array , if the nans
# are continuous, the diff will always be 1
# if not, diff will be > 1 , and using any() will return True
any(np.diff(aa) > 1)
```