# all vs and AND any vs or

Tags: python

I was eager to know about the what is the difference between python `all` and `and`, as well as `any` and `or`? For example:

```py
status1 = 100
status2 = 300
status3 = 400
```

Which is better to use:

```
if status1 == 100 and status2 == 300 and status3 == 400:
```

or

```
if all([status1 == 100, status2 == 300, status3 == 400]):
```

similarly for the any and or condition:

```
if status1 == 100 or status2 == 300 or status3 == 400:
```

or

```
if any([status1 == 100, status2 == 300, status3 == 400]):
```

which one is more efficient, using the built-in functions or the primitive or and and conditions ?

Comment: If you do `all([status1==100,status2==300,status3=400])` it first has to create the whole list, so I guess `and` is better. Might be different with a generator, though.

Comment: You could [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to be sure, but I think that it will always be faster to use the logical operators than to construct a new list object and invoke a function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The keywords `and` and `or` follow Python's [short circuit evaluation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) rules.  Since `all` and `any` are functions, all arguments would be evaluated. It's possible to get different behaviour if some of the conditions are functions calls.

Comment: This is a solid and simple answer that gets to the point of the question. If all you need is an `if` statement and you have the variables in hand then using any/all is probably the wrong choice. any/all are meant to be used against a list of predicate functions. They are popular in functional style programming. Consider ``if any(isOdd(x) for x in data)``. Here you have data coming from somewhere and you want to make a decision about it.

Comment: All arguments to `any` or `all` will be evaluated, but their *truth values* may not be, as these functions are also short-circuiting - try `any(1 / i for i in [1, 0])`

Comment: In case you don't want to "try", the above evaluates to True. Indeed the 1/0 is not evaluated, since the 1/1 is already True. Swap the order of 1 and 0 and it baulks.

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr**

From what I know, `all` is better to use when you may be comparing a varying amount of boolean statements and using `and` is much better for a finite boolean statement, and when using `all`, try to use a generator function.

**Explanation in detail**

**Edit** (for clarity of use of the term short-ciruit)
Their usage in finite statements is preferred because `Python` will short circuit the evaluation of each Boolean statement once the Truth can be determined. **See end of answer for proof and detailed example of this.**

Since any statement comprised of successive `and` statements will be `False` if at least one statement is `False` then the compiler knows to check only until it reaches one false answer:

```
status1 == 100 and status2 == 300 and status3 == 400
```

It will check `status1 == 100` if this were found to be `False`, it would immeadiately stop processing the statement, if it were `True` if would now check `status2 == 300`, etc.

This kind of logic can be visually demonstrated using a loop:

Image we were writing the behavior for the and statement, you would check each statement along the line and determine if all of them are `True` and return `True` or we would find a `False` value and return `False`.  You can save time after reaching the first false statement and just quit immediately.

```
def and(statements):
    for statement in statements:
        if not statement:
            return False
    return True
```

and for `or` we would write logic that would exit as soon as a `True` statement is found, as this proves all or statements to be irrelevant to the overall truth of the statement as a whole:

```
def or(statements):
    for statement in statements:
        if statement:
            return True
    return False
```

This logic is of course mixed and intertwined appropriately obeying order of operations when `and` and `or` statements are mixed together

The `and` and `any` statements serve to avoid this situation:

```
collection_of_numbers = [100,200,300,400,500,600,.....]
if collection_of_numbers[0] == 100 and collection_of_numbers[1] == 200 and .......:
    print "All these numbers make up a linear set with slope 100"
else:
    print "There was a break in the pattern!!!"
```

Similarly with `or`

```
collection_of_numbers = [100,200,300,400,500,600,.....]
if collection_of_numbers[0] == 100 or collection_of_numbers[1] == 200 or .......:
    print "One of these numbers was a multiple of 100"
else:
    print "None of these numbers were multiples of 100"
```

for example:

```
temp = []
itr = 0
for i in collection_of_numbers:
    temp.append(i == itr)
    itr += 100
if all(temp):
    print "The numbers in our collection represent a linear set with slope 100"
else:
    print "The numbers in out collection do not represent a linear set with slope 100"
```

A kind of silly example, but I think it demonstrates the type of scenario when `all` might be of some use.

A Similar argument is made for any:

```
temp = []
for i in collection_of_numbers:
    temp.append(i%3 == 0)
if any(temp):
    print "There was at least one number in our collect that was divisible by three"
else:
    print "There were no numbers in our collection divisible by three"
```

Though it could be argued that you will save a lot more time implementing this kind of logic using loops.

for `and` instead of `all`:

```
itr = 0
result = True
for i in collection_of_numbers:
    if not i == itr:
        result = False
        break
    itr += 100
if result:
    print "The numbers in our collection represent a linear set with slope 100"
else:
    print "The numbers in out collection do not represent a linear set with slope 100"
```

The difference being this will break before checking every single entry, saving a lot of time in large sets where an early entry breaks your condition.

for `or` instead of `any`:

```
temp = []
result = False
for i in collection_of_numbers:
    if i%3 == 0:
        result = True
        break
if result:
    print "There was at least one number in our collect that was divisible by three"
else:
    print "There were no numbers in our collection divisible by three"
```

This will check until it finds one to meet the condition as anything after that will not change how `True` the statement is.

** Edit ** Example for above use of short circuit phrasing and proof of statement.
Consider

```
1 == 2 and 2 == 2
```

and

```
all([1 == 2, 2 == 2])
```

the first statement will evaluate `1 == 2` to be `False` and the statement as a whole will immeadiately short-circuit and be evaulated to `False`.  Whereas the second statement will evaluate `1 == 2` to be `False`, `2 == 2` to be `True`, then upon entering the function `and` it will now return `False`.  The extra step of having to evaluate each statement first is why it is preferable if you are checking some small case finite set of boolean checks to not use the function.

While inconsequential with two statements, if you take an extreme example you will see what I mean by the evaluation of all the boolean statements is short circuited.  The below test evaluates `1000` Boolean statements in different fashions and times their execution time.  Each statements first Boolean statement would cause a short circuit *on the boolean statement as a whole* but not on the *evaluation*.

**test.py**

```
import timeit

explicit_and_test = "1 == 0 and " + " and ".join(str(i) + " == " + str(i) for i in range(1000))

t = timeit.Timer(explicit_and_test)
print t.timeit()

function_and_test = "all([1 == 0, " + ", ".join(str(i) + " == " + str(i) for i in range(1000)) + "])"

t = timeit.Timer(function_and_test)
print t.timeit()

setup = """def test_gen(n):
    yield 1 == 0
    for i in xrange(1,n):
        yield i == i"""

generator_and_test = "all(i for i in test_gen(1000))"

t = timeit.Timer(generator_and_test,setup=setup)
print t.timeit()
```

And when run:

```
$ python test.py
0.0311999320984      # explicit and statement
26.3016459942        # List of statements using all()
0.795602083206       # Generator using all()
```

The effects of the short circuit evaluation of statements is clearly evident here by an exorbitant factor.  You can see that even still the best approach for any sort of finite Boolean statement is to use an explicit statement, and as I stated in the beginning of my lengthy answer.  These functions exist for cases where you may not know how many Boolean statements you need to evaluate.

Comment: Your `any()` example is very inefficient - why not use a generator comprehension? In fact, with the ternary operator, you could condense it into a one-liner: `print 'foo' if any(i%3 == 0 for i in collection_of_numbers) else 'bar'`

Comment: @AirThomas while you are correct, as I mentioned they are silly examples which were used to illustrate explicitly what `any` and `all` are doing, i.e. evaluating on a set of `boolean`s.  Without any _shortcuts_.  My answer was meant to go into as explicit and obvious detail (possibly at the expense of efficiency) since this question boiled down to an understanding of what these two built-in commands do in order to be able to compare their functionality against explicit boolean statements.

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you put into this answer, but your very premise is is false; `any` and `all` are [guaranteed to be equivalent to the functions you rewrote as `and` and `or`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), which means [they really do short-circuit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14730046/2359271). To illustrate explicitly what these functions are doing, you need to post lower-level source.

Comment: @AirThomas I don't believe I said they do not follow short circuit evaluation?  My two functions `and` and `or` were written to give the OP some insight into how these functions work.  I don't think my premise (`all is better to use when you may be comparing a varying amount of boolean statments and using and is much better for a finite boolean statement.`) is false at all, I would be interested to hear why you think it is?

Comment: I was referring to: "Their [`and`'s] usage in finite statements is preferred because Python will short circuit statements once the Truth can be determined."

Comment: @AirThomas I clarified my answer as to which type of short circuiting I was referring to: please refer to my edit for detailed explanation.  You were making a gross assumption on what I meant by short circuiting, in computer programming there are many short circuiting mechanisms built into compilers and interpreters.

Comment: @AirThomas I think this could have been clarified a lot earlier with a question instead of an accusation.