# Is any() evaluated lazily?

Tags: python

I am writing a script in which i have to test numbers against a number of conditions. If **any** of the conditions are met i want to return `True` and i want to do that the fastest way possible.

My first idea was to use `any()` instead of nested `if` statements or multiple `or` linking my conditions. Since i would be satisfied if any of the conditions were `True` i could really benefit from `any()` being lazy and returning True as soon as it could.

Based on the fact that the following print happens instantly and not after 10 (= 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) seconds i assume it is. Is that the case or am i somehow mistaken?

```
import time

def some(sec):
    time.sleep(sec)
    return True

print(any(some(x) for x in range(5)))
```

Comment: Yes - it's lazy...

Comment: thanks! The same holds for `all()` i imagine

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: I think *lazy* is probably the wrong term here - they will *short circuit* as soon as possible is probably more accurate

Comment: @Chris_Rands well - all can short circuit as soon as something *doesn't* meet the condition...

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `all()` can short-circuit if one condition isn't met.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730046/is-the-shortcircuit-behaviour-of-pythons-any-all-explicit

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, `any()` and `all()` short-circuit, aborting as soon as the outcome is clear: See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> **all(iterable)**
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```
>
> **any(iterable)**
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is
>   empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

Comment: i usually find the docs bad but in this case it is beyond clear. Thanks a lot! Also this is exactly what i had in mind in terms of _lazy evaluation_. how is _short-circuiting_ any different ?

Comment: The generator expression is lazy in the sense that it only calls `some(x)` when the next item is requested. `any/all` short-circuit in the sense that it will only request items until the outcome is clear. You could say that `any([some(x) for x in range(5)])` still short-circuits, but isn't lazy since the list comprehension results in `some` being called on all elements of `range(x)` before `any` begins, but `any` will still stop examining the input list as soon as possible.

Answer (score 16):

While the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) functions short-circuit on the first "true" element of an iterable, the iterable itself may be constructed in a non-lazy way. Consider this example:

```
>> any(x == 100 for x in range(10**8))
True
```

This will take several seconds to execute in Python 2 as `range(10**8)` constructs a list of 10**8 elements. The same expression runs instantly in Python 3, where `range()` is lazy.

Comment: I find this confusing because I know that `range()` creates the full list in python2, but then you wrap it in a generator, which is lazy

Comment: @Chris_Rands: When you use a *generator expression*, like in the example above, the `for`-expression is immediately evaluated. Hence, `range()` constructs a full list even before the generator is run.

Answer (score 10):

As Tim correctly mentioned, `any` and `all` do short-circuit, but in your code, what makes it *lazy* is the use of [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension). For example, the following code would not be lazy:

```
print(any([slow_operation(x) for x in big_list]))
```

The list would be fully constructed and calculated, and only then passed as an argument to `any`.

Generators, on the other hand, are iterables that calculate each item on demand. They can be [expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), [functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), or sometimes manually implemented as lazy [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's lazy as demonstrated by the following:

```
def some(x, result=True):
    print(x)
    return result

>>> print(any(some(x) for x in range(5)))
0
True

>>> print(any(some(x, False) for x in range(5)))
0
1
2
3
4
False
```

In the first run `any()` halted after testing the first item, i.e. it short circuited the evaluation.

In the second run `any()` continued testing until the sequence was exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and here is an experiment that shows it even more definitively than your timing experiment:

```
import random

def some(x):
    print(x, end = ', ')
    return random.random() < 0.25

for i in range(5):
    print(any(some(x) for x in range(10)))
```

typical run:

```
0, 1, 2, True
0, 1, True
0, True
0, 1, 2, 3, True
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, False
```

Answer (score 1):

No. All and Any support shortcircuiting but they don't make the conditionals interpretation lazy.

If you want an All or Any using lazy evaluation you need to pass them a generator. Or else the values get evaluated in the moment the list/set/iterator/whatever is constructed

Comment: this is actually the only correct answer.

Here is an example

```
a = []

any([True, a[0]])
```

Will fail

Alternatively, using OR (or and) will not fail since its not a function:

    ```
    a = []
    True or a[0]
    ```

Answer (score -1):

JoshiRaez is the actual correct answer.

Here is an example

```
a = []

any([True, a[0]])
```

will fail

On the other side, using OR (or AND) will not fail since its not a function:

```
a = []
True or a[0]
```