# Python lazy multiple conditions check

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

I have a lot of conditions to check, but condition evaluation is heavy (e.g. condition requires database access), so I have to check them lazily.

Normally, such check could be written in `if` clause:

```
if type in FOOD_PRIZES and Prize.objects.filter(type=type).exists():
    pass
```

If the number of conditions are increasing then `if` clause becomes ugly.

I can make list of condition lambdas and use `all` method, but it looks ugly too:

```
conditions = [
  lambda: type in FOOD_PRIZES,
  lambda: Prize.objects.filter(type=type).exists()
] 

if all(condition() for condition in conditions):
   pass
```

Is there a better way to make code shorter? Is there another ways to make conditions lazy?

Comment: You could do `if a == b == c == d:`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a python question since you state that the issue is due to query time. In that case, the python code makes no difference; it's a micro optimisation.

Comment: @vaultah I used `a == b` as an example. Condition could be something heavy like Django `exists` method.

Comment: Given that your objection is that your solution *"looks ugly"* and you ask for one that *"looks better"*, which is wholly based on your opinion, how do you even expect this to get answered?

Comment: @potykion what do your *actual* conditions look like?

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, is there a way to make code shorter that list of lambdas with `all` call?

Comment: Why do you want it to be *shorter*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I like to write less code, but since shorter code does not mean better code, then my question is not about code style. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to continue what you're doing — but **put your fastest conditions to check first.**

[`all()` will short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348588/is-any-evaluated-lazily), meaning that as soon as a condition evaluates to `False`, it will stop processing conditions, saving you the time you would expend by running the other queries.

As for what *looks* best — that's up to you. But it's far better to have effective, readable code than "attractive" code! And short code isn't always better. Verbosity often makes code more readable to others.

Just be careful. For example, if subsequent conditions are dependent on the first, using `all` can break. For example, given `x='6.5'`, `if isinstance(x, float) and x>5.5` would work but `all((isinstance(x, float), x>5.5))` would error.