# Why does using `any` here cause this program to hang, but using a `for` loop doesn't?

Tags: python, recursion, caching, dynamic-programming

## Input

```py
sum_possible(2017, [4, 2, 10]) # -> False
```

## Usage of `any` which causes the solution to hang / take a long time

```py
def sum_possible(amount, numbers, cache = None):
  if cache is None:
    cache = {}
  if amount in cache:
    return cache[amount]
  if amount == 0:
    return True
  if amount < 0:
    return False
  cache[amount] = any([sum_possible(amount - number, numbers, cache) for number in numbers])
  return cache[amount]
```

## Usage of a `for` loop which solves the solution in a reasonable time

```py
def sum_possible(amount, numbers, cache = None):
  if cache is None:
    cache = {}
  if amount in cache:
    return cache[amount]
  if amount == 0:
    return True
  if amount < 0:
    return False
  
  for number in numbers:
    if sum_possible(amount - number, numbers, cache):
      cache[amount] = True
      return True
  
  cache[amount] = False
  return False
```

I thought that `any` would short-circuit? Effectively `return True`ing early if it encountered a `True`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600865/6273251 TL;DR list comprehension fully evaluates before `any()` does. It's the list comprehension that's taking a long time I think.

Comment: Just remove the square brackets `[ ]`, which look innocuous but effectively prevent `any( )` from short-circuiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any()` would short-circuit, but you're building a list to pass to `any` first.

```
cache[amount] = any([sum_possible(amount - number, numbers, cache) for number in numbers])
```

The list comprehension is evaluated first - and it's eager:

```
[sum_possible(amount - number, numbers, cache) for number in numbers]
```

Replace it with a generator expression - that should work (lazy eval):

```
cache[amount] = any(sum_possible(amount - number, numbers, cache) for number in numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a thing I was definitely missing. Interestingly however, using the generator expression still causes `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` for me, whereas using the `for` loop doesn't. Is there anything more that could possibly be amiss?

Comment: The early exit is missing from the `any` version - that may be the issue.

Comment: I think that might be worth a separate question, I'm going to mark this as resolved since the first issue was definitely the eager list comprehension evaluation as you pointed out.

Comment: Can you add a link to the new question in the comments here, if you do post a new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69803975/5196424